# Unable to solve maven dependency issue

Tags: maven

[Hi, im just started using maven, and tried to learn how it works, i got stuck in to following code and getting error in this code, please help me with this, also not able to create build path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CoGQ.png)

Comment: Please read some other questions and find out how to properly write one. Add your POM as text, explain what you want to do and add all error messages (as text) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

`maven-plugin` should be used only if you're developing a plugin. From what I see it looks like your project is a web application, so you should use either `jar` or `war` as packaging